# Why tail to same file create a empty file, or empty the file?

Tags: pipe, tail

I try to maintain the last lines of a file, but when `tail -n 10 test.txt > test.txt` create or empty the file...

SO: Ubuntu server

**Example**:

```
#test.txt file 20 May 23 12:24 test.txt
 a
 a
 a
 a
 a
 a
 a
 a
 a
 a
```

use `tail -n 10 test.txt > test.txt`
new file is empty  `0 May 23 12:36 test.txt`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Output [Redirection by the shell](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Redirections.html) (as well as input redirection) happens *before* the requested command is started. The <kbd>> file</kbd> output redirect opens `file`for writing and creates `file` if it does not exist; if it does exist it is truncated to zero size.

Once that has happened and your `tail` command is started it can only read an empty file...